# Logging into an intranet externally with Python

Tags: python, web-services, http, windows-7

If my company has an external intranet website that uses IIS windows Authentication how can I log onto it with a script in Python. We access the website with the url: `intranet.company.com`.

We login with `DOMAIN\username` and our network password. I tried to use Firebug to see the HTTP header routine but found nothing really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to implement NTLM authentication, take a look at [python-ntlm](https://github.com/mullender/python-ntlm) library available on google code.